# convert const std::shared_ptr<const T> into boost::shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, boost, constants, shared-ptr

I need convert a variable type of `const std::shared_ptr<const T>` into `boost::shared_ptr<T>`.

In the following `scanCallback()`, I can not modify the param `const std::shared_ptr<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan> msg`. The `msg` is very big in memory, which contains large lidar points.  `PushScanPacket()` func's arg is `boost::shared_ptr<io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan>`, which I also can not modify its type.
The following code does not compile successfully, does somebody know how to  do this?

```
void HesaiLidarModule::scanCallback(
    const std::shared_ptr<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan> msg){
    std::remove_const<const std::shared_ptr<
                            const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan> 
                     >::type non_const_msg(msg);
    boost::shared_ptr<io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan> msg_boost(non_const_msg.get());
    hsdk->PushScanPacket(msg_boost);
}
```

UPDATE_1st: The following code can compile successfully, but i'm not sure whether `std::remove_const<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan>::type non_const_obj(*msg);` induces a copy operator, which is expensive for `msg`.

```
void HesaiLidarModule::scanCallback(
    const std::shared_ptr<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan> msg){
    std::remove_const<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan>::type non_const_obj(*msg);
    io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan& copy = non_const_obj;          
    boost::shared_ptr<io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan> msg_boost(&copy);
    hsdk->PushScanPacket(msg_boost);
}
```

Comment: Split this into two steps, one is to remove the `const`, the other is the conversion. That said, the obvious flaw in your approach is that you take a raw pointer and then put it under management of a smart pointer that doesn't know anything about the other smart pointer. Now both think they own the resource, which then causes dangling pointers plus double delete. Further, your question lacks a [mcve] and the full error message, but should also be split in two. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `std::remove_const<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan>::type` is simply `io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan`.

Comment: Second code does a copy, but worst, it passes reference/ownership of a local variable to a `shared_ptr`, leading to UB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot transfer ownership from `std::shared_ptr` to `boost::shared_ptr`.
You might from a `std::unique_ptr` though.

But you can create a `boost::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter.

```
boost::shared_ptr<io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan>
    msg_boost(const_cast<io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan*>(msg.get()),
              [msg = msg](auto*) mutable { msg.reset(); });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fq6YnqMq4)

Deleter captures original `shared_ptr` to maintain the lifetime,
and instead of releasing the resource, it just "decreases" the refcount.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42,  when build with the aboving code,  `error: expected ‘)’ before ‘mutable’`.  When using with  `[msg](auto*) mutable { msg.reset(); }`,  `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan_<std::allocator<void> > >::reset() const’`

Comment: @narutojxl: typo fixed. (misplaced `mutable`).

Comment: Hello,  @Jarod42, with typo fixed, it seem not allowed.
```error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<const io_adaptor::msg::PandarScan_<std::allocator<void> > >::reset() const’
  189 |          [msg](auto*) mutable { msg.reset(); } );```

Comment: @narutojxl: `[msg = msg]` fixes the *"const"* capture. Demo added (with simpler types).

Comment: thanks very much for your help, i need learn C++ more